# How to disable favourites from loading when using the Super key

Tags: gnome, window-managers

I am not a new Linux user but I am new to Gnome which is the preferred WM at work so I'm trying to get it to work they way I prefer.

The primary issue is that I want to have key-bindings of `Super+1`, `Super+2`, `etc..` to switch between windows. I have made this work this with the following commands which generally work great.

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-1 "['<Super>1']"
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-2 "['<Super>2']"
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-3 "['<Super>3']"
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-4 "['<Super>4']"
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-5 "['<Super>5']"
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-6 "['<Super>6']"
```

However throughout my day sometimes Gnome overwrites these and suddenly `Super+2` will load Thunderbird or take to me the window where Thunderbird is running. I can't find how to disable this behaviour and it's becoming infuriating. Rerunning the `dconf` commands do not fix it. Can anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: See this topic for more insight about this problem https://askubuntu.com/questions/968103/disable-the-default-app-key-supernum-functionality-on-ubuntu-17-10-and-later